# Export LDAP address book entries to HTML

Tags: software-rec, html, export, ldap

#### Preface

- we're setting up a company-wide search that should be able to search every bit of information
- our CRM software offers LDAP access to the in-application address book
- the search engine is *not able* to index contact data from LDAP - it can work on HTML pages and files only

#### Question

The easiest way to get the address book data available for the search engine is to generate a HTML page for each address book entry.

Are there existing open source solutions that we can use to generate (and update) that HTML pages?

The features we'd need are:

- Support for 1000+ contacts
- Nice HTML pages, valid HTML code
- Index file with link to every single page
- Support for objectClass `person`
- Support for multivalued mail fields
- Grouping of fields (company address fields grouped, home address fields grouped)

---

## ldap2html

From http://www.mylinuxproject.de/nf-index-mylinuxenglish-ldap_e.html works with some fixes, but internally uses `ldapsearch` without paging, so we don't get more than 500 entries.

Also, it generates one big list only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could roll your own - you could make a webserver out of PHP or perl and it would create your own HTML.  There's quite a few LDAP admin tools that have HTML interfaces that could take you a good percentage of the way there.

Comment: Can you list some of these tools that have HTML interfaces? I'm only aware of phpLDAPadmin.

Comment: @cweiske a search on sourceforge.net will grab a bunch for you

Comment: "LDAP admin tools" returns nothing on sourceforge.net "LDAP tools" does

Answer (score 0):

I've made my own tool; it's available at https://github.com/netresearch/ldap2html